# Sourcing ./zshrc generates an if statement that considerably slows down shell load time each time

Tags: python-3.x, zsh, zshrc, pyenv

As the title suggests, everytime I open/source my ./zshrc the following code is generated

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Eventually, I have that code copy&pasted a hundred times (inside my ./zshrc) and considerably slows down my shell load time.

What is this code, and how do I stop it from reappearing?

Comment: Why don't you remove it from your .zshrc, if you don't want it? Or do you want to say that some mysterious process actually updates .zshrc behind your back? This would be creepy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval "$(pyenv init -)"` initializes `pyenv`, so you can use it in your shell. `pyenv` is a tool for installing and managing multiple version of Python.

To see what it does, just run

```sh
pyenv init -
```

in your shell. After that, copy-paste the output of the command into your `~/.zshrc` file and remove the code you listed above. Your shell will start up much faster after this. Should `pyenv` ever stop working for you, just run `pyenv init -` again and update your `~/.zshrc` file with its output.

Oh, and by the way: [Doing `source ~/.zshrc` is generally a **bad idea**.](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#weird-things-happen-after-typing-source-zshrc) Instead, if you've modified your `.zshrc` file and you want to see the results, just restart your terminal or do `exec zsh`.

---

## Update

@akBo I just read your question again and realized that what you are actually saying that the block of code you've posted is added again and again to your `~/.zshrc` file.

Have you perhaps added the following to your `.zshrc` file somewhere?

```sh
echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.zshrc
```

This comes from the [`pyenv` installation instructions](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/2a3b286b71c659e32b49ef6f274349662d2a18e0/README.md#installation), but is **not** something you should add to your `.zshrc` file. Rather, your meant to run that on your command line *once* so that the block of code you posted is added to your `.zshrc` file. But because you've instead added that line to your `.zshrc`, it gets executed each time your `.zshrc` gets sourced and thus again and again adds the same block of code.

Just remove the line I posted above from your `~/.zshrc` file and you should be fine.

Comment: Running `pyenv init -` *once* is unlikely to significantly slow shell startup. The OP indicates it appears a hundred times. Removed the 99 redundant occurrences should be sufficient.

Comment: @chepner Actually, now that I read the question again, I think we are both wrong: The OP says that the block of code he posted is _added to their `.zshrc`_ each time he sources it. There must be some other code in their `.zshrc` that generates it.

Comment: That does sound likely. +1

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the help